# How to run custom function in a specific window and work in background?

Tags: autoit

I wrote a script using [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/). 
The problem is to run it in background so that I can use my desktop for other work.

I used `_ImageSearch()` which usually works on an active window. 
Is there any way to call such a function in background? Here is my code:

```
WinActivate('Window Title')

$x = 0
$y = 0

If _ImageSearch('searchButton.PNG', 1, $x, $y, 20) = 1 Then
   Return 1
ElseIf _ImageSearch('bundle.PNG', 1, $x, $y, 20) = 1 Then
   Send('{ESC}{LCTRL}{LCTRL}{LCTRL}')
   sleep(1000)
Else
   Send('{LCTRL}')
EndIf
```

Comment: sadly, `imagesearch` works with the screen, not with the application, so "working in background" isn't possible by design.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that runs continuously and call the image search with a hotkey:

```
HotKeySet('+!e', '_endScript')   ; terminate the script with SHIFT+ALT+E
HotKeySet('+!i', '_searchImage') ; calls the image search function with SHIFT+ALT+I

; main loop
While True
    Sleep(50)
WEnd

Func _endScript()
    Exit
EndFunc

Func _searchImage()
    ; your image search stuff
EndFunc
```

But it may be that the other application blocks your hotkeys. Try it.